# how to dynamically add new textboxes and dropdownlist and saving them to multiple rows in sql database?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I've been stuck in this problem for a while. I already searched in google, but all of them use javascript. How to save the multiple values to multiple rows in database?

here is my code:

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">

   function addRow(data) {

       var table = document.getElementById(data);

       var rowCount = table.rows.length;
       var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

       var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

       for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {

           var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

           newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
           //alert(newcell.childNodes);
           switch (newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
               case "text":
                   newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                   break;
               case "checkbox":
                   newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                   break;
               case "select-one":
                   newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                   break;
           }
       }
   }


</SCRIPT>

<table style="width: 100%;"><tr><td><h3 style="text-decoration: underline"></h3></td></tr></table>
    <table style="width: 100%;" rules="all">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100px">Stokereta</td>
            <td style="width: 80px">Jenis Roda</td>
            <td style="width: 100px">No Siri</td>
            <td style="width: 80px">Saiz Roda (mm)</td>
            <td style="width: 50px">Flange (mm)</td>
            <td style="width: 50px">Hollow (mm)</td>
            <td style="width: 100px">Tindakan</td>
            <td style="width: 100px">Skidded</td>
            <td style="width: 350px">Catatan</td>

        </tr>
        </table>


        <table style="width: 100%;" id="data" rules="all">
        <tr>
            <td >
                <asp:TextBox ID="stokereta" runat="server" Width="100" BorderStyle="None" ></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_jenisroda" runat="server" Width="80" >
                </asp:DropDownList>

            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="nosiri" runat="server" Width="100" BorderStyle="None" ></asp:TextBox>

            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="saizroda" runat="server" Width="80" BorderStyle="None" ></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="flange" runat="server" Width="50" BorderStyle="None" ></asp:TextBox>
            </td>

            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="hollow" runat="server" Width="50" BorderStyle="None" ></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_tindakan" runat="server" Width="100" >
                <asp:ListItem>Pilih..</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Reprofiling</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Rediscing</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>


            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_skid" runat="server" Width="100" >
                <asp:ListItem>Pilih..</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Ya</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Tidak</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
```

```
    </table>


    <br />
    <input id="Button2" type="button" value="Tambah" onclick="addRow('data')" style="border: thin ridge #000000"  />

    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Proses" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
    <br />

    <br />
<asp:Button ID="send" runat="server" Text="Hantar" BorderColor="Black" Width="60px" OnClick="Send_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="clear" runat="server" Text="Semula" BorderColor="Black" Width="60px" OnClick="Semula_Click"/><br />
```

code behind:

```
Protected Sub Save()


    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)

    conn.Open()

    Dim n As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(kuantiti.Text)


    For i As Integer = 0 To n - 1 Step +1
        If i = 0 Then
            Dim s As String
            s = "Insert into butiran_hantar ([depoh],[siriSA],[kuantiti],[date],[stokereta],[jenisroda], " +
            "[nosiri],[saizroda],[flange],[hollow],[tindakan],[skid],[catatan],[status]) " +
            "select (@depoh,@siriSA,@kuantiti,@date,@stokereta,@jenisroda, " +
            "@nosiri,@saizroda,@flange,@hollow,@tindakan,@skid,@catatan,@status)  "
            Dim sqlcomm As New SqlCommand(s, conn)


            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@depoh", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = depohlist.SelectedValue
            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@siriSA", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Convert.ToInt32(lblsiri.Text.Trim())
            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@kuantiti", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(kuantiti.Text.Trim())
            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(tarikh.Text)
            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@stokereta", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stokereta.Text
            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@jenisroda", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddl_jenisroda.SelectedItem.Text
            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@nosiri", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Convert.ToInt32(nosiri.Text)
            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@saizroda", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(saizroda.Text)
            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@flange", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(flange.Text)
            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@hollow", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(hollow.Text)
            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@tindakan", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddl_tindakan.SelectedValue
            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@skid", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = ddl_skid.SelectedValue
            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@catatan", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = catatan.Text
            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Label3.Text


            'sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ulasandm", ulasandm.Text)
            Try
                sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery()

                Label2.Text = "Data disimpan."

            Catch ex As Exception
                Label2.Text = ex.Message.ToString()
            End Try

        Else
            Dim sqlcomm As New SqlCommand("Insert into butiran_hantar ([depoh],[siriSA],[kuantiti],[date],[stokereta],[jenisroda], " +
            "[nosiri],[saizroda],[flange],[hollow],[tindakan],[skid],[catatan],[status]) " +
            "values (@depoh,@siriSA,@kuantiti,@date,@stokereta,@jenisroda, " +
            "@nosiri,@saizroda,@flange,@hollow,@tindakan,@skid,@catatan,@status)", conn)

            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@depoh", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = depohlist.SelectedValue
            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@siriSA", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Convert.ToInt32(lblsiri.Text.Trim())
            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@kuantiti", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(kuantiti.Text.Trim())
            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(tarikh.Text)
            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@stokereta", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stokereta.Text
            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@jenisroda", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddl_jenisroda.SelectedItem.Text
            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@nosiri", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Convert.ToInt32(nosiri.Text.Trim())
            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@saizroda", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(saizroda.Text.Trim())
            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@flange", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(flange.Text.Trim())
            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@hollow", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(hollow.Text.Trim())
            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@tindakan", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddl_tindakan.SelectedValue
            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@skid", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = ddl_skid.SelectedValue
            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@catatan", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = catatan.Text
            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Label3.Text
            'sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ulasandm", ulasandm.Text)
            Try
                sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery()

                Label2.Text = "Data disimpan."

            Catch ex As Exception
                Label2.Text = ex.Message.ToString()
            End Try
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It´s unlikely people will want to go through all that code. How about you explain better what you want and where are you stuck.

Comment: I'm no ASP.Net expert but from what I know I thought surely someone would have needed something like this and there are plenty of pages in the web about dinamically adding controls, like this one: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19493/Adding-controls-to-asp-net-dynamically-and-persist

Comment: ok sorry madth3..actually i want to dynamically adding textboxes and dropdown to my form.user will key in data (7 textbox & 2 dropdown).thats for 1 row..in my case user will add new row to key in some more data..so basically how to adding multiple txtbox & dropdown and then save them to database in multiple rows (for easy to achieve later). lots of code i found suggest in javascript to add txtbox..but i dont know how to insert into sql database if using javascript

Comment: The link I added did not seem to use JavaScript and it does mention persistence. When searching make sure you use the terms "asp.net" and "controls".

Comment: but i want to know how  to insert multiple values to multiple rows in sql database..do you know how to do it?